# CSS folder not getting exported to developed node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules

I have developed a node module and hosted. I am installing that package in one of my application but it is not importing the CSS folder.

When I build the node module codebase in local, it creates the CSS folder inside "dist" folder. What configuration is needed to expose css assets from my module?

Comment: What tool are you using to create you node module?

Comment: @soundslikeodd, hi, I am using Webpack as bundler.